# update many nested objects in mongoose

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

is there a way to update many nested objects in mongoose all at once ? i can update one nested object like this :

```
    Model.findOneAndUpdate(
    {name : watchlistName , "mentions.id" : 123},
    {
        $set : {
            "mentions.$.tone" : positive,
            "mentions.$.verified" : true
        }
    }, function (err) {
        if(err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
    }
    );
```

but if i have let's say 200 id to update, how should i proceed ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Model's [update](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.update) method for this.

```
Model.update(
    {name : watchlistName , "mentions.id": { $in: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] }},
    {
        $set : {
            "mentions.$.tone" : positive,
            "mentions.$.verified" : true
        }
    }, function (err) {
        if(err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
    }
);
```

If you need to update them with different values I'd suggest to do it this way:

```
const docs = await Model.find({name : watchlistName , "mentions.id": { $in: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] }}).exec();

docs.forEach((doc) => {
  doc.mentions.$.tone = '[docValue]';
});

await Promise.all(docs.map(async doc => await doc.save()));
// All docs are updated now
```

Comment: This would just update ONE nested object.. i want update many objects :
mentions.id : 123, mentions.id : 456, mentions.id : 777 etc...

Comment: @TasDePixels I see, misunderstood you then, sorry. Updated the code. Seems like you need `$in` selector

Comment: Thank's a lot, but how can i assign a distinctive value for each id ?
For example id 1 takes positive tone, 2 take negative. And so on..

Comment: @TasDePixels Hm... I'm not sure that's it's possible... I think the best approach here will be to query all the documents you need and update them separately.